# What if I could prevent a conversation from turning into pure guesswork?

Tags: conversations, difficult-people, netherlands

I've had some serious stuff to handle over the last month or so. And it sadly wasn't the stuff you could keep easily quiet. To make things worse, the main actor that created this mess has apparently a notorious reputation and there's plenty of gossip about them to keep people talking about this for hours.

So, all the family, half the town, they all knew what was happening with me and wanting to gossip about this other person at me. And while I didn't mind them asking once in a while what was happening and how things were going, what *did* massively annoy me is that I did not figure out a way to get these conversations to stick to the facts.

I've had dozens of conversations with family and family friends, and they all went something like this: when asked for the current status of things, I would give people the list of facts. I would honestly tell them A, B and C had already happened and I was waiting on certain people/organisations to tell me about X, Y and Z. Just imagine someone rattling of a grocery list: That was me. After that not working a few times, I also started to add little sentences like 'And that's all I know for now' or 'I'll see what happens next, speculating only drives me crazy'.

Sadly, none of that worked. The conversations invariably ended up with the other person going "And what if..." or "I heard rumors that..." with some harebrained speculation on how bad things could potentially get or already are. I ended up handling these by trying to say that I didn't know what would happen if, only to have people speculate even further on what could happen if. I tried handling them by saying it is speculation and wouldn't be helpful, only to have people switch to another 'what-if'.

I think the breaking point for me was when someone said 'You seem stressed by all this' and then continued adding more what-ifs and gossip on worst outcomes. I wanted to strangle that person (don't worry, didn't do it.). At the same time, even plain out telling this person that yes I was stressed and could they please not add to it by speculating/gossiping didn't stop them.

To be clear, I don't mind the conversation continuing. But it should stick to the facts, which means the only way I can see one continuing is with someone asking me things like 'What does this term mean' or 'What is the process you just mentioned like' instead of gossiping or speculating about possible consequences.

Most of these conversations took place when randomly encountering family or family friends. Physically walking away from the conversation or bluntly ending it with 'If you're going to gossip or speculate I'm going to go now' isn't an option, as that would be perceived as rude instead of polite.

So, given my previous approaches and them not working, apart from physically walking away from the conversation to signify it is over, **what can I do better to make a conversation stick to the facts and not degrade into gossip and speculation?**

Comment: Are those conversations by phone or in-person? If they are in-person, where do they usually take place?

Comment: @Ael they are mostly in-person though 1 or 2 were over WhatsApp. As for where they take place, that was mostly when encountering family while e.g. visiting grandparents, when family came to our place.. but a lot was just when I encountered people on the streets and they stopped me to talk. So I wouldn't mind if answers focused on that first and foremost: Dealing with these people while you encounter them outside.

Comment: Do you want to continue the conversation about said topic (as long as everybody sticks to the facts) or do you just want to end the conversation about that topic, and possibly start talking about a new topic?

Comment: @JeroendeK I wouldn't mind to continue the topic, but like you I have wondered how to without the speculation and gossip. The only thing I can come up with would be people needing me to explain part of a process or terminology. Other than that I can't think of any way the conversation could continue...

Comment: That seems obvious but I'm assuming you want to stay polite?

Comment: @Ael yes. That's why just walking away isn't really an option, as are the more blunt ways of cutting off the conversation like saying 'If you only have gossip and speculation, I'm going to go now'

Comment: From personal experience: going through Socrates triple filter helped. And informing people that what they are doing is not helping (because they thought hey are helping).

Comment: I have no idea what "Socrates triple filter" is, but since it apparently helped you, maybe you could turn this comment into an answer? (and explaining in it what is this "Socrate thing" and what personal experience you have with that?)

Comment: @Ael : [Socrates triple filter](https://theeducator.ca/triple-filter-test/) is explained here (and many other places). Roughly, if what you want to tell me is neither **true**, **good** or **useful** , why bother telling me?

Comment: @OldPadawan that's all nice and well, but you can apply that to yourself or to someone asking you whether they should share some gossip with you. How do you apply it to people that have already shared gossip? I also have an inkling my approach so far already meets all three (letting people know it's speculation - true, letting people know it only stresses me out/isn't helpful - good or useful).. but it's been proving very hard to get people to basically apply the filter to themselves before speaking! If Szczerzo has experience in doing so, I would be glad to hear.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell : I apply this to myself all the time as I *hate* gossip. My way of handling people after a friendly reminder is... say... quite not IPS at all I would say :D but none of my friends/acquaintances usually do that as they don't like it either so it's easier for me to handle it.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell When you tell them you are really stressed and you don't want speculation, do they just blow past that and keep speculating, or does the conversation just drift back to the speculation?

Comment: @DaveG It just 'blows past' it, in a sense that people start speculating about other stuff related to the same issue, or ... I'm not sure how to describe it, but it's almost like they start defending their reasons for speculating with gossip, if that makes sense? So, something like "I'm sorry, I thought my speculation should be taken into account because <$unfounded statement>", just not as directly said as that.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yeah that's the harder case.  If it was just that the conversation moves away and then drifts back, which is what happens with me & my best friend re the USA election, you can simply remind them that it's stressing you out.

Comment: @DaveG yeah, those are easier. I have a few friends and we actually do that, but it's harder with family and family friends because well, this is the major reason they even start a conversation and there's not much else to talk about.

Comment: Have you tried saying nothing about the speculation and just saying that talking about this stress you and you would rather not? What happens then? Do people also get defensive or just ignore what you said?

Comment: @Ael I haven't really. It would be a lie to claim that talking about the whole thing stresses me. It didn't, the whole thing is stressful in that it adds some stress and uncertainty to my life. But talking about the facts of that does not increase the stress levels. So I can't really use 'it stresses me to talk about this' as an excuse when the truth is that it only annoys me to talk about this in an unfactual way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the situation triggered your relatives and friends imagination, and that they were simply assuming you'd be willing to be part of imagining things also as kind of a shared activity. Some people (I'd include myself) also get ideas about how to behave in the future when they have a clear view of the possible outcomes, that include a degree of what-if and projections.

If you don't want to be part of this activity, because by nature the projection stresses you out, the problem is difficult to solve by any of the two ends, your intrapersonal problem with speculation, that is personal and out of scope, and other's natural and willing-to-help behavior, which is hard to change.

I think asking a person not to speculate or gossip wasn't effective because the person denied being gossiping/speculating. In my experience, it's difficult to obtain a fine-grain understanding from others and easier to behave so they have a rough but simpler idea of the problem.

When I had to draw a line to say no about someone good will, or declining a conversation, I usually invoked a pretext, and you are in a good position to have one. You could invoke being stressed by the topic to end conversation whenever it's not oriented the way you like it, quite simply. "I'm sorry, the topic stresses me and I'd prefer we speak about something else now".

Sometimes, when someone already started a conversation I dislike, I also have a way to notify this, that is to not acknowledge listening and having heard them like you usually do by nodding, saying yes or making eye contact. After some time, most people would stop and ask me acknowledgement, I'd drop the line I'd like to change subject equally.

I admit to some degree this could be an unsatisfying solution to the problem because they would not understand the real reason for dodging, and it's only a "saying-no" kind of answer not avoiding conversation entirely to happen (rather have a way to end it), but this would be my best try.

Comment: Invoking being stressed by the topic to end conversation would be a lie. I'm not additionally stressed by some stressful things being the topic of conversation, I'm annoyed by the way other people are speculating and gossiping about it. There's a big difference there and it is dishonest to ignore that and claim otherwise. I'm also not sure why you describe gossiping as a 'willing-to-help behavior'?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell People would naturally assume you don't mind or possibly like them to gossip about the situation, which is why I labelled this as being willing to help (although its not exactly that, it's more that they don't see any harm in that and assume it pleasurable for both of you). When it comes to your annoyance, I must admit I frankly don't get it, and I would not expect others to get it as well. Which is why I propose lying (if you call it such) or anyway trying to find a simple explanation (if you have a more honest one that's for the best, but at least easier to relate to)